# mvvm light silverlight - child windows for adding/editing orders

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

I'm developing a silverlight intranet application for my company, found mvvm to be an exciting pattern and would love to use it, also watched the videos of mvvm light toolkit.

I'm fairly confused about something, this might because I'm used to only working with winforms.

I have a page with a list of orders and 2 buttons, "edit" and "add", i can't figure out how to show the child windows to the user using the mvvm pattern.

I have a mainviewmodel and an orderviewmodel, the mainviewmodel has an observable collection of orderviewmodel.

I can get the orderlist populated fine, my only issue is figuring out how to show an edit window and an add window.. sticking to the pattern.

I'm not sure if I'm overthinking this.

I would greatly appreciate any help that could steer me in the right direction, let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance,
Claus

Edit: Not having coded in 10 years, my initial thought ofcourse was to create a new childwindow in the codebehind and override its constructor to take a orderviewmodel but i would rather do it the correct way.

Comment: I've found, not sure how I've missed it, a sample/walkthrough which might be perfect for my needs:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application

Master being on one form, details in a new window, might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a window and can add different child control

```
<Window x:Class="RetailPOS.Dashboard"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"          
        xmlns:Child="clr-namespace:RetailPOS.View.Usercontrols.MainWindow"
        x:Name="DashBoardCntrl"
           xmlns:WpfKb="clr-namespace:WpfKb.Controls;assembly=WpfKb"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024"  ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
            <Child:MergeUserInfoSearch x:Name="UserInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="1,0,0,0" Width="513"></Child:MergeUserInfoSearch>
             <Child:MenuControl x:Name="MenuCtrl" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="1,0,0,0" Width="510"></Child:MenuControl>
            <GroupBox Height="159" Margin="8 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="AliceBlue"  Header="Categories" Width="499">
                <Child:Categories  x:Name="cat" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="1,0,0,0" ></Child:Categories>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Height="360" Margin="5 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="AliceBlue" Header="Products">
                <Child:Products HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="prod"  Margin="1,0,0,0"></Child:Products>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel></Grid>
```